# Does inverse of a Gamma moment generating function have a known distribution?

Tags: probability, distributions, gamma-distribution, moments, moment-generating-function

I have come across a moment generating function for a random variable $Y$ of the following form
$$M_Y(t) = \mathbb E\left[e^{tY}\right] = \left[1 - \frac t \beta\right]^k.$$
So it is basically $[M_X(t)]^{-1}$ for some $X$ that is $\text{Gamma}(k, \beta)$ distributed. Is there a known distribution for $Y$?

Comment: Inverting the corresponding characteristic function indicates the original is a "generalized distribution" rather than a legitimate probability distribution.  How did you obtain this mgf?  Perhaps a mistake was made in its derivation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that. I don't think it was a mistake. I was calculating the MGF of a Stochastic Differential Equation with known MGF but with added noise in the drift. The result was a product of terms of the known MGF and the MGF that I have above. Can you clarify what you mean by "generalized distribution," as I know there is a generalized distribution for the Gamma?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics).